# Strange behaviour of '\b' escape sequence with '\n' in printf

Tags: c, terminal, escaping, printf

If I understand correctly `\b` escape sequence moves the active cursor position to the left and `\n` inserts a newline at the cursor position. But the following example is confusing.

```
λ> cat hello.c                               
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("hello,world\b\b\b\b\bWOR");
  return 0;
}

λ> cc hello.c && ./a.out
hello,WORλ> 
λ> cat hello.c          
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("hello,world\b\b\b\b\bWOR\n");
  return 0;
}

λ> cc hello.c && ./a.out                     
hello,WORld
λ>
```

In the first example, `\b\b\b\b\b` moves the cursor five positions to the left (after `,`) and inserts `W` followed by `O` and `R` and the characters in the original string after `,` are omitted. But, in the second example, usage of `\n` alters the behaviour of `b` in an unexpected way. The characters in the original string are overwritten and `\n` is inserted at the end, rather than at the cursor position. Can someone please explain this behaviour? (Or is it terminal dependent? I have tried on two different terminals.)

Comment: You expect text editor like behaviour. The characters on the right of the cursor will not be moved to the next line. It is a terminal window (what have you printed is there unless you printf something else there), not the text editor.

Comment: @P__J__ Can you please explain the overwriting behavior? Also, are the escape characters expanded at run-time?

Comment: @drake01: The conversion of `\b` to a backspace character and of `\n` to a new-line character occurs during program translation (compilation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In the first example, \b\b\b\b\b moves the cursor five positions to the left (after ,) and inserts W followed by O and R and the characters in the original string after , are omitted.

No, that is not what happens. First, “hello,world” is written. Then the five `\b` characters move the cursor position to the “w”. Then “WOR” is written, leaving “hello,WORld” in the display. Then your program ends, and the command-line shell resumes executing. It prints its prompt, “λ> ”. That overwrites the “ld”, leaving “hello,WORλ> ” in the display.

> But, in the second example, usage of \n alters the behaviour of b in an unexpected way. The characters in the original string are overwritten and \n is inserted at the end, rather than at the cursor position.

Again, no. “hello,world” is written, the `\b` characters move the cursor to “w”, then “WOR” is written, and we again have “hello,WORld” in the display. Then the `\n` advances the display to the next line, leaving “hello,WORld” in the previous line.

Comment: Beautifully explained. One query, why can't `\b` move over a `\n`(i.e. to the previous line)?

Comment: Also, what's the reason for removing `<stdio.h>` from the code?

Comment: @drake01: It can on some devices/systems/terminal emulators and not others. C 2018 5.2.2 2 says, of backspace, “… If the active position is at the initial position of a line, the behavior of the display device is unspecified.” So a C implementation might support this or might not. Keep in mind that, when C was being developed, we were using hardcopy teletypes, among other things, and many of those mechanically could not back up the paper to a previous line.

Comment: @drake01: `<stdio.h>` was not removed from the code; it was just accidentally hidden. I edited the question text from using code style to using “preformatted text”, to remove the syntax coloring that was affecting “hello,world”. But then Stack Overflow was interpreting the `<` and `>` as part of HTML. I edited again to fix that.